# Is this function well defined for any $g\in L^q(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, lebesgue-measure

If $p,q\in(1,\infty)$ such that $\frac 1q+\frac1p=1$, given $g\in L^q(\Omega)$ we difine: $$\Phi(g):L^p(\Omega)\to\Bbb R \\ \Phi(g)(f):= \int_{\Omega}fg$$
I know this is a basic question, but how do you show $\Phi$ is a well difined function for any $g\in L^q(\Omega)$? I mean, I'm getting confused, I thought that to show that a function is well defined you worked with the elements of the domain, in this case $L^p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Holder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), $$\|fg\|_{L^1} \le \|f\|_{L^p} \|g\|_{L^q}$$ Thus given $f \in L^p$ and $g \in L^q$, $fg \in L^1$, so $\int_{\Omega} fg$ makes sense as a real number.

Comment: ...or complex number, in case you're considering $L^p(\Omega)$ and $L^q(\Omega)$ over $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 2):

I think it means for a fixed g $\in$ $L^q$, any f $\in L^p$, $\Phi(g)(f)= \int_{\Omega}fg$ is finite, thus well-defined. Using Holder's inequality, you can see.